# what is the Time complexity of of two sum problem?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I'm practicing my Big O notation and in need of some clarity.
this is my solution from Leet code Two sums problem. Basically given a list and a target value, return the two index that add up to the target.
For example

```
twoSum([1,2,3,4],7)
```

would return [2,3]

I can see the solution on leetcode, but I want to check whether my assessment of this code is correct. Time complexity = O(n squared) because of the in operation for the array within the outer loop.
Is this correct?

The code is

```
def twoSum_n2(nums, target):
    for idx, value in enumerate(nums): #O(n)
        diff = target - value # O(1)
        try:
            diff_idx = nums.index(diff) #O(n)
        except ValueError as ex:
            continue
        if idx != diff_idx: # O(1)
            return [idx, diff_idx] #O(1)
    return []
```

Comment: Yup, in the worst case you are doing `n` operations (index) `n` times (loop), so `n^2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your current implementation it's O(n^2), because you have one O(n) inside another O(n). When we have similar situation, we need to multiply values of those O-s.

Answer (score 1):

```
diff_idx = nums.index(diff) #O(n)
```

The above line is going to be run n times since it is within the for loop going over the nums list. Hence the total number of times the check will be done is O(n^2) times, which brings the complexity to O(n^2).